# Loading an image from resources in an unreferenced assembly

Tags: image, resources, silverlight-2.0

I have two silverlight assemblies, CaseManager.Applet and CaseManager.Applet.Sample. The Sample assembly has a reference to the base Applet assembly. The sample assembly has an embedded resource png image. The base applet assembly has a view xaml that I wish to display that image programmatically.

In the sample assembly I have a bit of code that creates a Uri like so:

```
var icon = new AppletIcon()
                   {
                     ImageUri = new Uri("CaseManager.Applet.Sample;component/images/guiness_2.png", UriKind.Relative),
                     ModuleType = GetType(),
                     Text = "Sample Module"
                   };
```

When I execute this code all the properties of ImageUri throw InvalidOperationException. I am not sure why. Anyone have suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code does the job:

```
var icon = new AppletIcon()
                   {
                     ImageUri = new Uri("/CaseManager.Applet.Sample;component/images/guiness_2.png", UriKind.Relative),
                     Module = this,
                     Text = "Sample Icon"
                   };
```

Things to note here:

- The slash at the start of the Uri string.
- The short name of the assembly containing the resource.
- the ;component/ section.

From there it is basically the path inside your project to the image. Hope this helps someone else.

For what it was worth I was missing the very first slash.